# Php statement to show div

Tags: php, html

I'm having problem to get my different div from my php function

This is the code

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
if (!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin()) {
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("index.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
     if($fgmembersite->ChangePassword()){
        echo '<div id="ajaxDivOk">';
        sleep(3);
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("index.php"); 
     }
     else{
         echo '<div id="ajaxDivErro">';
         sleep(3);

     }
}
?>
<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>EBSPMA PAAD</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/modernizr.js?cb=2.2.3.2085"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header role="banner" class="main-header">
            <!-- MAIN HEADER -->
            <div class="main-header-body">
                <div class="container-wrapper">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <h2>
                                    PAAD-GesDocente</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1 main-header-title">
                                <p class="sizeToggle" >Mudar Password</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header><section class="content">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="box">
                    <form name="changepwd" id="loginForm" action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name='submitted' id='submitted'/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="path" value="painelAdquirente.action"/>
                        <div>
                            <p><b><font color="red">A sua password deve ser alterada!</font></b></p></div>
                        <div class="icon-input">
                            <label for="password"></label>
                            <div class="input password">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                <input type="password" name="oldpwd" id="oldpwd" placeholder="Senha antiga">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="icon-input">
                            <label for="password"></label>
                            <div class="input password">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                <input type="password" name="newpwd" id="newpwd" placeholder="Senha nova">
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $fgmembersite->UserEmail(); ?>">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" id="sbmtLogin" class="sa-btn1" value="Mudar">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div id="ajaxDivOk" name="ajaxDivOk" style="display:none" class="alert alert-success">Modificado com sucesso...Faça login novamente</div>  
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div id="ajaxDivErro" name="ajaxDivErro" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">Opss....Erro, tente mais tarde</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js?cb=2.2.3.2085"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The div is not show but in fiddler i get

```
<div id="ajaxDivOk">
```

So the php function is working properly since the password is changed and i should have the div

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: the code is send to the browser after the server build the document. so a sleep() does not what you expect. Furthermore your code produce invalid html code. pls take a look at the IPO Model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model)

Comment: your `sleep()` is pointless. all you're doing is delaying the server-side script by 3 seconds, by which time your `<div>` echo may not even have been sent out onto the wire. and you're echoing out the div **BEFORE** you even start your html document,s o you're generating bad/invalid html. **AND**, since you've already doin output, you can't do redirects anymore since you'll just end up with "headers already sent"

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set which notification you want to show up when you do your checks at the beginning, and then display the appropriate one in the following HTML. You can handle the redirect the same way.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    if ($fgmembersite->ChangePassword()) {
        $redirect = '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=index.php" />';
        $notice = '<div id="ajaxDivOk" name="ajaxDivOk" class="alert alert-success">
            Modificado com sucesso...Faça login novamente</div>';
    } else {
        $redirect = '';
        $notice = '<div id="ajaxDivErro" name="ajaxDivErro" class="alert alert-danger">
            Opss....Erro, tente mais tarde</div>';
    }
}
```

Then in the `<head>` of your document...

```
<head>
    <?php if isset($redirect) echo $redirect; ?>
    ...
```

And later where you are displaying the notifications:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php if isset($notice) echo $notice; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi...thanks for your reply...i have this error using this code "Notice: Undefined variable: redirect in newpass.php on line 32" . This line is the <head> <?php echo $redirect; ?>

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the upper code would only run after the form is submitted. You can just add some `isset` checks to handle that.